# Create page preview from Angular app route

Tags: javascript, angular

I have application with content display configurations from backend.
I can configure menu content, order and many different elements in that configurations.

How can I create full page preview to illustrate changes made in any configuration.

I mean:

I want display preview of page after changes made in configuration to illustrate those changes.

In the end result I want to generate html for page from single route and display it in different router outlet or replace content of another browser tab.

Comment: can you please add your code snippet so.. can help you :-)

Comment: I don't have anything yet more than Angular app. I don't know where to start with preview. For start `ng new app` and first page for preview is `localhost:4200` `route: { path: '', component: AppComponent }`